# How to fetch data from OneSignal Wordpress post in Android app?

Tags: android, wordpress, push-notification, onesignal

I have a Wordpress site with OneSignal as push notification service, but I have a need which is: I want to fetch post id in my Android app whenever a user opens the notifications so as to determine which Activity to open?

Answer (score 1):

How to get post id from response as receiving launch url and body?

Sample response is

```
result {"action":{"type":0},"notification":{"isAppInFocus":false,"shown":true,"androidNotificationId":-216570404,"displayType":0,"payload":{"notificationID":"a3d651a1-e67b-4c82-ada8-c5f03e8b08f0","title":"OdishaReporter","body":"???????? ??????? ?? ???????? ???????","launchURL":"http:\/\/odishareporter.in\/odisha\/protest-in-delhi-on-kundali-issue\/","lockScreenVisibility":1,"fromProjectNumber":"995873670600","priority":0,"rawPayload":"{\"google.sent_time\":1518685044953,\"google.ttl\":259200,\"custom\":\"{\\\"u\\\":\\\"http:\\\\\\\/\\\\\\\/odishareporter.in\\\\\\\/odisha\\\\\\\/protest-in-delhi-on-kundali-issue\\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"i\\\":\\\"a3d651a1-e67b-4c82-ada8-c5f03e8b08f0\\\"}\",\"from\":\"995873670600\",\"alert\":\"???????? ??????? ?? ???????? ???????\",\"title\":\"OdishaReporter\",\"google.message_id\":\"0:1518685044961958%6229cc87f9fd7ecd\",\"notificationId\":-216570404}"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i actually found a hack around this. this what i did:

```
 public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;

        String slug = getWebMediaName(result.notification.payload.launchURL);
        String notificationBody = (result.notification.payload.body != null) ?
                result.notification.payload.body : "";
}
```

i found out that i could also find a post with is slug on wordpress so long as you have REST API enabled on your server

```
private String getWebMediaName(String val){
//split the string and then find your slug which is usually the last 
//characters after the "/" forward slash character
}
```